# convertion between record and tuple?

Tags: sml

Now that `tuple` is just `record` in SML, I tried:

[image]

The codes above I hope this record can accept a tuple, but it reports an error.

So, there's no implicit conversion from tuple to record and from record to tuple(though didn't post here, I have tried at local actually).

My question is why SML doesn't supply such conversion?(because these conversions are quite frequent in c++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples are records with members named 1 through n. That is, the three element tuple `(a, b, c)` is really a record `{1 = a, 2 = b, 3 = c}`. So there doesn't need to be an implicit conversion between tuples and records because they're already the same thing.

Now the function you defined takes a record with the members `x`, `y` and `z` and you pass it a record with the members `1`, `2` and `3`. This doesn't work. For this to work there'd need to be an implicit conversion between records with different member names, which seems like a very bad idea.

> (because these conversions are quite frequent in c++)

There are no implicit conversions in C++ between unrelated structs or classes with different members (or even the same members). To do that, you'd need a `reinterpret_cast` (or a C-style pointer cast on the address), which is neither common nor a good idea (and wouldn't work with anything but POD types).